# Creating new pandas dataframe by extracting columns from other dataframes - ValueError

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have to extract columns from different pandas dataframes and merge them into a single new dataframe. This is what I am doing:

```
newdf=pd.DataFrame()
newdf['col1']=sorted(df1.columndf1.unique())
newdf['col2']=df2.columndf2.unique(),
newdf['col3']=df3.columndf3.unique()
newdf
```

I am sure that the three columns have the same length (I have checked) but I get the error

```
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

I have tried to pass them as pd.Series but the result is the same. I am on Python 2.7.

Comment: All three columns have same unique values in your case?

Comment: no they are different for each column, but the length of the `.unique()` objects is the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there is problem length of unique values is different.

One possible solution is concat all data together and apply `unique`.
If unique data not same sizes, get `NaN`s in last values of columns.

```
newdf = pd.concat([df1.columndf1, df2.columndf2, df3.columndf3], axis=1)
          .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.unique()))
```

EDIT:

Another possible solution:

```
a = sorted(df1.columndf1.unique())
b = list(df2.columndf2.unique())
c = list(df3.columndf3.unique())

newdf=pd.DataFrame({'col1':a, 'col2':b, 'col3':c})
```

Comment: But if I check with `len(sorted(df1.columndf1.unique())==len(df2.columndf2.unique())` and `len(df2.columndf2.unique())==len(df3.columndf3.unique())` I get true for both.

Comment: Iteresting, so if check `print (len(df1.columndf1.unique()))`, then `print (len(df2.columndf2.unique()))` and `print (len(df3.columndf3.unique()))` all values are same?

Comment: Yes! just checked

Comment: OK, so if use my code there is no `NaN`s in last row?

Comment: I get `cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object`, probably because, if I check the types, I get `type list` for df1.column, don't really know why

Comment: oh yeah maybe because I am sorting it! But this is something I need.

Comment: Hmmm, if omit `sorted` how does it work? And if omit `newdf['col1']=sorted(df1.columndf1.unique())` it working?

Comment: Nope, if I omit `newdf['col1']=sorted(df1.columndf1.unique())` I get the same error. The same if I omit sorted.

Comment: New solution was added, but not sure if working. Can you check it?

Comment: Ok working, thanks a lot, really. just out of curiosity, any idea what was wrong in my approach?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea, never seen it before. But I get one last idea - try change `newdf['col2']=df2.columndf2.unique(),
newdf['col3']=df3.columndf3.unique()` to `newdf['col2']=list(df2.columndf2.unique()),
newdf['col3']=list(df3.columndf3.unique())`.

Comment: Ok this works too... so I just had to cast all the columns to list. Don't know why I couldn't think of it before. Thanks, I really appreciate!

Comment: You are welcome! I think problem is `unique` return numpy array, not `list`s